# Android: Drawing to canvas, way to make bottom left correspond to (0,0)?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I'm trying to write a graph class I can use in Android(I'm aware pre-made ones exist), but converting all of my coordinates would be a pain. Is there an easy way to make the screen coordinates start at the bottom left?

Comment: All of the comments so far address this in different ways (creative!) I would think you would still want to add more context to your question, like why and what you then expect "left" and "up" to be at that point

Comment: I agree with the above, it's slightly vague, so for reference: The accepted answer creates a coordinate system with its origin in the bottom left corner of the screen, with domain X = [0, `canvas.getWidth()`), Y = [0, `canvas.getHeight()`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, I don't know of a way to move `0,0` to the bottom left and get what you would typically think of as "normal" coordinates.

But combining `scale()` and `translate()` might do the trick to achieve the same effect.

```
canvas.translate(0,canvas.getHeight());   // reset where 0,0 is located
canvas.scale(1,-1);    // invert
```

Comment: Nothing is drawing after I do this.

Comment: The translation needs to come before the scale. Since you're scaling first, the translation is shifting the canvas the opposite direction that you intend. Also remember to call `canvas.save()` before the transformation and `canvas.restore()` after you've completed drawing.

Comment: The problem was you need to call translate() before scale(), works now.

Comment: I will update the code in the above answer to match the comments!

Comment: I wonder why do almost all code samples contain, and why do so many people suggest canvas.save() and canvas.restore(). If I omit them the code works the same, Android still seems to do these before/after onDraw()

Comment: This suggestion will make your text rendering upside-down.

Comment: Yeah, about that upside-down text.  Calling canvas.scale(1, 1) before drawing text and calling canvas.scale(1,-1) when done does not fix the problem.  Neither does using canvas.save() and canvas.restore().  Anybody have an answer to the text-upside down problem?

Comment: Note: this lines need to be placed before any actual rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip your Canvas with something like `canvas.scale(1, -1)` and then translate it to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canvas.translate()` [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29) to move the origin to where you want.

Answer (score 0):

The android canvas has the origin at the top left. You want to translate this to the bottom right. To do this translation, subtract the y co-ordinate from the Canvas height.

```
float X1 = xStart;
float Y1 = canvas.getHeight() - yStart;  //canvas is a Canvas object
float X2 = xEnd;
float Y2 = canvas.getHeight() - yEnd;
canvas.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, paint ); //paint is a Paint object
```

This should make your line start from the bottom left.